# Creating a macro to subset a monthly data into smaller datasets based on date in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro, do-loops

I'm working on a large dataset which have data for a whole month with around 42 variables, and I want to create separate datasets for every day of the month.

How can I create a macro which will do it properly? The date variable is `trans_date` and month is March.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in SAS, you would not create separate datasets for each day.  Rather, you would perform your analysis `BY` the date variable.  That has the same effect - i.e., whatever analysis you do will be done separately for each different value in the date variable.